# Limit nodes in views per group

Tags: 7, views, entities

I'm using Group field in views. There are several events in one month. How can i limit my events. 2 events should be displayed in every month.

**July**
Event 1
Event 2
Event 3
Event 4

**August**
Event 1
Event 2

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to write custom code you can use the 
[views limit group](https://drupal.org/project/views_limit_grouping) module

> This is a basic Views style plugin that allows for a limit on the number of rows displayed within a grouping field.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the custom code option would actually be the useful answer for longevity...how does one accomplish this?